# Tweepy reply to tweet in stream

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a twitter bot that responds to tweets containing a hashtag. I've been using the `twt = api.search(q='param')` to pull tweets and it's been working perfectly but I've since switched to `myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
twt = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())` to pull tweets in real time. this isn't working though and I don't know why. Here's my code:

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
twt = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())

twt.filter(track=['#www'], async=True)

#list of specific strings we want to omit from responses
badWords = ['xxx','yyy' ]

#list of specific strings I want to check for in tweets and reply to

genericparam = ['@zzz']

def does_contain_words(tweet, wordsToCheck):
    for word in wordsToCheck:
        if word in tweet:
            return True
    return False

for currentTweet in twt:
    #if the tweet contains a good word and doesn't contain a bad word
    if does_contain_words(currentTweet.text, genericparam) and not does_contain_words(currentTweet.text, badWords):
        #reply to tweet
        screen = currentTweet.user.screen_name
        message = "@%s this is a reply" % (screen)
        currentTweet = api.update_status(message, currentTweet.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is you're trying to send the reply through the stream instead of using an http request in a separate thread. It's not possible to do this as explained here:

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

Comment: please post an answer and then references.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across this.

When you create `myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(self.api)` self.api instance you want to use needs to be passed to StreamListner constructor or it will be null.